# Как обрезать картинку по размеру окна слайдера? bxslider

Tags: slider, html, вёрстка, css

Здравствуйте!

Не подскажите, как сделать так, чтобы bxslider картинку не ресайзил под размер отображаемой области, а просто обрезал ее и центрировал посередине?

Т.е. если картинка больше, чем viewport слайдера, то она просто режется и центрируется, и можно так листать!

Т.е. bx-viewport 600x300, а картинка 900x450, как сделать так, чтобы именно и отображалась только область в 600x300, от всего размера картинки?

Заранее благодарен за помощь!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если у вас фиксированный "вьюпорт", можно реализовать вот так:

```
<div class="slider-place">
    <ul class="my-slider">
        <li style="background-image:url('/url/to/image.jpg');"></li>
        <li style="background-image:url('/url/to/image.jpg');"></li>
        <li style="background-image:url('/url/to/image.jpg');"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Накидал пример: http://jsfiddle.net/L2bqmptc/2/

Также если нужно "вписать" картинку, то это делается одной строчкой:

`background-size: cover;`